# Refresh/Reload CustomView in Android

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view, custom-view

I have a CustomView that shows a number on its View and this digit came from the database. that works fine in the first place, when I move to another Activity, change the database amount and call `finish();` method, the first Activity will Appear and I want to refresh or reload the CustomView that initialized in the first load to show its updated value. how is it possible?

here is my CustomClass:

```
public class Navigation extends LinearLayout {


public Navigation(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.initComponent(context);
}

public Navigation(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.initComponent(context);
}

private void initComponent(Context context) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.navigation_bar, null, false);
    this.setOrientation(VERTICAL);
    this.addView(v);

    LinearLayout workorder = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.workorder);

    PersianTextView workorder_count = (PersianTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.workorder_count);

    workorder.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            getContext().startActivity(new Intent(getContext(),Workorders.class));
        }
    });

    database db = new database(getContext());
    db.open();
    Cursor cu = db.Display_shared("SELECT * FROM [Workorder_Repair] WHERE [Workorder_Repair_For_Department_ID] = "+ Login.dep_id+" AND [Workorder_Repair_Status] = 1");

    if(cu.getCount()>0)
        workorder_count.setText(""+cu.getCount());
    else
        workorder_count.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);

}
```

I use it in almost 15 activities and I want to refresh it

Comment: How do you show the number in the View in the first place? This should be the exact same.

Comment: Also, how do you start the second activity? Are you using startActivity() or startActivityForResult()?

Comment: I start it by staratActivity() method

Comment: Did you miss my other question?

Comment: Also if the view codes run in onResume, problem will be solved.. that's the point @Code-Apprentice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add a function called `update();` in my CustomView and call it from first Activity's `onResume`  method like this:

```
((CustomView) findViewById(R.id.customview)).update();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch value from database and update its value and assign to your custom view by calling either activity's `onResume()` method or `onActivityResult()` method

```
package com.dialogdemo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class Navigation extends LinearLayout {

    PersianTextView workorder_count;
    public Navigation(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.initComponent(context);
    }

    public Navigation(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.initComponent(context);
    }

    private void initComponent(Context context) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.navigation_bar, null, false);
        this.setOrientation(VERTICAL);
        this.addView(v);

        LinearLayout workorder = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.workorder);

         workorder_count = (PersianTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.workorder_count);

        workorder.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                getContext().startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), Workorders.class));
            }
        });

        refreshView();

    }

    public void refreshView(){
        database db = new database(getContext());
        db.open();
        Cursor cu = db.Display_shared("SELECT * FROM [Workorder_Repair] WHERE [Workorder_Repair_For_Department_ID] = " + Login.dep_id + " AND [Workorder_Repair_Status] = 1");

        if (cu.getCount() > 0)
            workorder_count.setText("" + cu.getCount());
        else
            workorder_count.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

call `refreshView()` method in `onResume()` in all yours activities it will work

Comment: I want to call the CustomView Codes on onResume but they will called only in setContentView method!

Comment: Okay so in that case you have to find out id for that views at first time and after that you will use these ids for further purpose of updation

Comment: For more clear show me your custom view class so that I can refer it out

Comment: I did add my class to question @MohitTrivedi